# How can I refer to implementations of a method in annotation processing?

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I am playing around with Java (javax) annotation processing.

Suppose I have an annotation for methods:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MethodAnnotation { }
```

Now I want to process all the methods which are overridden from a type with the annotated method:

```
interface MyInterface() {
    @MethodAnnotation
    void f()
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    override void f() { } // <- I want to process this method
}
```

`@Inherited` meta-annotation seems not to be suitable here:

> Note that this meta-annotation type has no effect if the annotated type is used to annotate anything other than a class.

Also, is it possible to process an inherited class method which is not overridden in a subclass? Like this:

```
class MyClass {
    @MethodAnnotation
    void f() { }
}

class MySubClass extends MyClass { } // <- I want to process its f()
                                     //    or at least to find out that it doesn't
                                     //    override the method
```

How can I access the overriden methods of a certain method within `AbstractProcessor`?

I guess, to achieve this I need to find subclasses of the eclosing class, but I haven't found a way to do this either.

**UPD**: I suppose it's possible using `RoundEnvironment.getRootElements()` but still found no proper way of doing this.

Comment: Can you not iterate all the hierarchy (super classes and interfaces) of your class and look for each interfaces and super classes which methods have the annotation ?

Comment: @davidhxxx, I guessed the annotation processing goes the other way: it triggers at the code elements with annotations, doesn't it? If so, I need to find the overridden methods without the annotations giving the declared method that has it.

Comment: Sorry, you refer about javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor. 
I though that you want to do a processing on annotations :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer is that out-of-the-box annotation processing isn't going to make this easy for you, but it *can* be done.

Rather than using the normal dispatch mechanism for processing, you're actually going to have to process *every* method and do the filtering yourself.

### Step 1:

Define your processor so that it [supports all annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html#getSupportedAnnotationTypes--) by using `"*"` as its supported annotation type.  This will mean that your processor will get invoked every round.

### Step 2:

Use [`getRootElements`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/RoundEnvironment.html#getRootElements--) to get the entire set of elements every round.

### Step 3:

Create an [`ElementScanner8`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/ElementScanner8.html) to traverse any element that you find to look for `ExecutableElement`s.  If you're willing to trust that overridden methods are annotated with `@Override`, you can do a quick filter on those. Otherwise, just look at all of them.

### Step 4:

Now you need to see if the method overrides a method with the annotation you're looking for.  There's no easy way to get methods that a given method has overridden, so you need to get the [enclosing element](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#getEnclosingElement--) of the method, look at its [superclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html#getSuperclass--) and [implemented interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html#getInterfaces--) (recursively), get their [enclosed elements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html#getEnclosedElements--), [filter out the methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/ElementFilter.html#methodsIn(java.lang.Iterable)), and [test to see if it has been overridden](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Elements.html#overrides-javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement-javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement-javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement-) by the method in question.  If it has, you can check the [annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#getAnnotationMirrors--) to see if it has one you care about.

### Step 5:

At this point, you should have the overriding method, the overridden method and the annotation mirror that you were looking for, so you should be able to implement whatever logic you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

according to the javadoc of `javax.annotation.processing.Processor` in Jsr269-1.8

> An annotation is present if it meets the definition of being present
>   given in AnnotatedConstruct. In brief, an annotation is considered
>   present for the purposes of discovery if it is directly present or
>   present via inheritance. An annotation is not considered present by
>   virtue of being wrapped by a container annotation...

The JavaDoc of [AnnotatedConstruct#getAnnotationsByType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/AnnotatedConstruct.html#getAnnotationsByType-java.lang.Class-) says that it returns indirectly present annotations, so I think you should scan for methods and check if they indirectly have the annotation using this call. Something in the spirit of [this](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=jsr308-langtools-master/test/tools/javac/processing/model/type/BasicAnnoTests.java).

Disclaimer... haven't tried it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Method annotations are not inherited. Type annotations can be inherited through the use of "@Inherited" annotation.

What you could do is define a functional interface with an inherited type annotation, however I don't know if this is elegant enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

If those annotations are available at runtime, and you want to reach them at runtime, you can use the [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library.

For example:

```
Collection<URL> urls = ClasspathHelper.forPackage("nl.shopname.location.domain");

Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
    new ConfigurationBuilder().setUrls(urls).setScanners(new FieldAnnotationsScanner()));

Set<Field> fieldsWithAnnotation = reflections.getFieldsAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately my goal is to perform some compile-time code verifying, so I need compile-time processing.